# sendEmail not working from Apex code/Anonymous Window

Tags: apex, code

I am executing below simple lines of code to trigger an email to my Inbox. I am not receiving the mail and also I see on the logs that there are no errors
Access level is already All Email in my org.

Please could anyone having knowledge of possible issue and solution, kindly comment. Thanks

**Apex code executed from Anonymous Window:**

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email_Custom =new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
String[] toAddresses = new list<string> {'xxxx@gmail.com'};
string subject='test';
string plainBody='test';
email_Custom.setSubject(subject);
email_Custom.setToAddresses( toAddresses );
email_Custom.setPlainTextBody(plainBody);
Messaging.SendEmailResult [] r = Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {email_Custom});
system.debug('r --> ' + r);
```

**Logs :**

13:04:35:426 USER_DEBUG [8]|DEBUG|r --> (Messaging.SendEmailResult[getErrors=();isSuccess=true;])

Noticed that even thru email send button from the Salesforce org (case or contact or lead Object) , mails are not being received.

Regards

Comment: Did you test email deliverability to your email ?

Comment: Ensure you are checking your spam folder

Comment: @NagendraSingh - Yes tested  email deliverability to your email

Comment: @CloudConnect - Yes checked the same. Have not received mail.

Comment: Can you navigate to setup> Email Logfiles> Request logs for the time the action is being performed on the dev console > Look for the [Mail Event](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_logs_format.htm&type=5) value ? Does it show R/D/T/P ?

Comment: @Swetha - Yes I dis validate that. That looks fine. Values are R and D

Answer (score -1):

I am facing a similar issue. In my client's org, all emails worked fine, but since a couple days back some stopped coming.
I went to some research and found [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MN3GIAW).
Might be related to the Salesforce Instance you are using and when it is being refreshed.
So, if I got it right, we need to open a Salesforce Case to get help.

Source:

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000MN3GIAW

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000387977&type=1

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381883&type=1

***Hope it helps, buddy.***

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/190058)